# Function is not being used. Why?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was wondering why this happens (In the pictures) The function is not being used. Why is that and how could it be used? Thanks! :)

```
def hello():
    def hi():
        h = input("Hey")
        if h == "Hey":
            print("hi")
            exit()
        exit()
```

In the below picture you can see what I mean.

[image]

Comment: Please post your code in this question, and not as an image. The reason why you are getting that "warning" is because you never called `hi()` in `hello()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, please post your code directly into your question, not as an image. I edited the question as it is suggested to be.

Did you ever call function `hello` or `hi`? You should call the function to execute it. Defining them does nothing. The following code will do what you intended.

```
def hello():
    def hi():
        h = input("Hey")
        if h == "Hey":
            print("hi")
            exit()
        exit()
    hi()
hello()
```